# Why is this alias including a parameter working?

Tags: bash, function, parameters, alias

Since variables are problematic when specifying an alias in Bash (in the `.bashrc`), something like the following isn't working:

```
alias count1="num=$1 | cat $num | wc"
alias count2="`cat $num` | wc"
```

Why is

```
alias killID="kill -9 `pgrep $1`"
```

working then?

Btw. when searching about this I learned that we should always use functions in the `.bashrc` to define something like the above. Just made me curious.

**edit**

Other example which isn't working with a parameter (because my first example is bad):

```
alias testalias='du -m ./* | sort -nr | head -n $1 ; du -sh'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first cases you are using pipes, when you should be using a group.

Also, you are using the wrong kind of quotes, you should be using single quotes, not double.  Using double quotes will give the value of variables at the time you declare the `alias`, not at the time you run the command.

These are also examples of useless use of `cat`.  See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Example:

```
alias count1='num=$1;wc $num'
```

In the command that works the `$1` expansion is never used.  It is not stored in the alias.  The parameter (being on the right) is appended to the constructed command at runtime.  Check the constructed alias with the `alias` command to see what it really does.

Comment: I noticed the wrong piping in `count1` just as you posted this. And I know that this is useless use of cat. It's just an example. The info with the quotes is interesting, I didn't know that. But the real question isn't solved: Why is it working for the alias killID?

Comment: See edit:  basically using `$1` in an alias does not work, you need to use a function instead.

Comment: OK. So your fixed version of `count1` isn't working either I guess.

Comment: I see your last sentence of the edit now. Thx, you are right. The alias `killID` just works for an ID (like `kill`) and not for an process name.